# How do I provide my own DateTimeProvider with Spring Data

Tags: kotlin, datetime, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to provide a transactionally consistent set of datetimes

```kotlin
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope
import org.springframework.data.auditing.DateTimeProvider
import org.springframework.transaction.support.SimpleTransactionScope
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.util.Optional

@Configuration
open class TransactionScopeTimeConfiguration {

  @Bean
  open fun transactionBFPP(): BeanFactoryPostProcessor =
    BeanFactoryPostProcessor { it.registerScope("transaction", SimpleTransactionScope()) }

  @Bean
  @Scope("transaction")
  open fun nowInstant(): Instant = Instant.now()

  @Bean
  @Scope("transaction")
  open fun nowOffsetDateTime(nowInstant: Instant): OffsetDateTime = nowInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)

  @Bean
  open fun transactionDateTimeProvider(factory: ObjectFactory<OffsetDateTime>): DateTimeProvider =
    DateTimeProvider { Optional.of(factory.`object`) }
}
```

However, when debugging my test I note that the function inside of `transactionDateTimeProvider` is never called (the creation of the Bean is)

```kotlin
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest

@DataJpaTest
@Import(TransactionScopeTimeConfiguration)
internal open class ExceptionDaoTest {
  @Test
  fun save(@Autowired exceptionDao: ExceptionJpaDao) {
    val toCreate = ExceptionEntity("someid")
    val saved = exceptionDao.save(toCreate)

    assertThat(saved).isInstanceOf(ExceptionEntity::class.java)
      .extracting({ it.id }, { it.businessDivisionId })
      .containsExactly(toCreate.id, "someid")
      .doesNotContainNull()

    assertThat(saved.lastModifiedOn).isSameAs(saved.createdOn)
  }
}
```

The test actually passes, but I haven't actually exercised this functionality in this test. It's important that any other datetimes are transactionally consistent with the audit traits.

Comment: Is there a bean of  type `ObjectFactory<OffsetDateTime>` in the context?

Comment: @Andrey that's not how `ObjectFactory` works, for any Bean/Component/Etc you create, you can always create an object factory from it, so yes `nowOffsetDateTime`. as I stated, the `transactionDateTimeProvider` is actually created fine (it would not be if the factory didn't exist), however the implementing function/object factory, is never called.

Comment: Personally, I usually create the DateTimeProvider as:
` @Bean fun offsetDateTimeProvider(): DateTimeProvider = DateTimeProvider = Optional.of(OffsetDateTime.now())`

regarding your assertion `assertThat(saved.lastModifiedOn).isSameAs(saved.createdOn)`
I don't think that will ever work because `OffsetDateTime` has nanoseconds precision and audit traits set `createdAt` and updatedAt in two steps so nanoseconds will very probably change.

Comment: @IlTera that's the purpose of using transaction scope, within a transaction there should only ever be one instance.

Comment: nope.... the transaction assures that data is persisted in ACID, I'm talking about the "java" part where code is executed at different times.

Comment: @IlTera no not that, SimpleTransactionScope  ensure that an object's lifecyle is the transaction https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/SimpleTransactionScope.html